# How can I pass the message content of postfix to the filter?

Tags: php, filter, pipe, postfix-mta

I have been following Postfix documentation and [this](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail) guide. On [this](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) manual for pipe, there appears to be no parameter for which the entire message can be directed as an argument to the filter. How can the message be passed to the filter without being saved in a file on the hard disk?

Comment: The guide is now available here https://web.archive.org/web/20150513100223/http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a pipe filter in master.cf the entire email (headers, from, to, body etc) will be sent to the filter/script.

The guide you showed sets a postfix flag of `F`. I would change that to `X` which means the external script dictates the final delivery and once it's delivered to that script will set the email as delivered and not store it anywhere else.